# Easy way to migrate a large R project from Windows to WSL with file reference changes?

Tags: windows, r

I have a large R project developed in a Windows environment which I want to move to Linux, and there are lots of Windows style directory references (assigned in variables at least) which I assume I will need to translate.  There are various folder tree references in the code.

Is there an easy way to do this, other than moving through all of the code?

Sections like:

```
SourceRootDir = "G:/blahblahblah/"
SourceDir = paste0(SourceRootDir, "RSource/")
```

needs to go to (I assume)... maybe the G:, C: drive references are all I need to change?

```
SourceRootDir = "~/blahblahblah/"
SourceDir = paste0(SourceRootDir, "RSource/")
```

Comment: It is difficult to see why "search and replace" isn't the answer with the way this question is phrased. There might be a software design problem in here, but I think you need to [edit] your question to provide more context. Note that asking for help with coding problems is off-topic, but help with software design issues is on-topic.